# Submitting form automatically using javascript instead of pressing button

Tags: javascript, forms, debugging, submit, extract

Using javascript how I can extract all states information at one go?

This page list in form, states to see the local service center address:

http://www.lenovowarranty.co.in/contacttech.asp

Should I save the page and modify the javascript?
Which debugger is best for javascript?

Answer (score 0):

You could post your form using [jQuery Forms](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/#getting-started). To automatically submit you should be able to do something like:

```
$(function(){
    $('#myFormId').ajaxForm().ajaxSubmit();
});
```

The ajaxSubmit function takes the same arguments as the regular [$.ajax()](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax#options).

For debugging javascript and many other things I think [Firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) for [Firefox](http://www.mozilla.com/firefox/) is the best.

Here's a short introduction http://getfirebug.com/video/Intro2FB.htm

Answer (score 0):

You can submit a form by calling its `submit` method:

```
document.forms[0].submit();
```

[This](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/forms.html) excellent page shows how to work with forms in JavaScript - submit them, check the values of the input elements etc.

Comment: I think he wants all results in one go, without refreshing the page.

Answer (score 0):

If you check the form, you'll see that it makes POST requests:

```
<form name="splocator" method="post" action="serviceproviders.asp" ...>
```

You can see which variables get sent and then you can make requests for all states via AJAX and interpret the responses.

You should consider using something like jQuery for this, especially if you're not experienced with JS.